# getSelectedItem().toString() выдает адрес с БД, а не значение выбранного элемента в спиннере

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-sqlite, cursor

Есть спиннер product заполненный значениями из БД с помощью курсорлоадера, есть еще один спиннер description который так же заполнен с помощью курсорлоадера, суть такова, выбираем в первом спиннере значение Х и во втором спиннере выводится список возможных характеристик этого Х, для реализации я хотел использовать `static String where`, `where =spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();`которую я вызвал для формирования запроса в курсорлоадере для description, но ничего не работало, с помощью тестового TextView выяснил что значение where присваивается не в виде значения как написано в спиннер для чего собственно `toString` и вызывается, а в виде `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@3423d556`+ при выборе новых элементов, значение не обновляется, но это скорее просто надо использовать какой-нибудь `notifyDataSetChanged()` (если нет, то поправте), как я понял отображается адрес откуда значение из БД, Вопрос : как сделать чтобы присваивалось значение в том виде в котором оно отображается в спиннере? и почему то не работают даже надстройки отображения текста `((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(18);`

```
public class MovingActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter, mAdapter;
static final int product = 0;
static final int description = 1;
SQLiteDatabase db;
public TextView text;
static String where = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.moving);
    db = new DirectBaseHelper(this).getWritableDatabase();
    text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);

    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_product);
    String[] from = new String[]{DirectTable.Cols.PRODUCT};
    int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
    scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, null, from, to, 0);
    spinner.setAdapter(scAdapter);
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(product, null, this);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(18);
            where = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(description,null,MovingActivity.this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });

    getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(description,null,this);

    final Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_decription);
    String[] fromDescript = new String[]{DirectTable.Cols.DESCRIPTION};
    int[] toDescript = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, null, fromDescript, toDescript, 1);
    sp.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(description, null, this);
    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    db.close();
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new MyCursorLoader(this, db, id);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    switch (loader.getId()) {
        case product:
            scAdapter.swapCursor(data);
            break;
        case description:
            mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
}

static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor cursor;
    int LOADER_ID;

    public MyCursorLoader(Context context, SQLiteDatabase db, int id) {
        super(context);
        this.db = db;
        LOADER_ID = id;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {
        switch (LOADER_ID) {
            case product:
                cursor = db.query(DirectTable.NAME, new String[]{"_id", DirectTable.Cols.PRODUCT}, null, null,
                        DirectTable.Cols.PRODUCT, null, null);
                break;
            case description:
                cursor = db.query(DirectTable.NAME, new String[]{"_id", DirectTable.Cols.DESCRIPTION},
                        DirectTable.Cols.PRODUCT + "= ?",new String[]{where}, null, null, null);
        }
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
 Cursor cursor=(Cursor)spinner.getSelectedItem();
 where=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DirectTable.Cols.PRODUCT));
```